# Standard deviations or two variances

Tags: statistics

Two variances or standard deviations? Listed below are the numbers of years that popes and British monarchs lived after their election or coronation.Treat the values as simple random samples from a larger population. Use a 0.05 significance level to test the claim that both populations of longevity times have the same variation. Popes: 2, 9, 21, 3, 6, 10, 18, 11, 6, 25, 23, 6, 2, 15, 32, 25, 11, 8, 17, 19, 5, 15, 0, 26 Kings and Queens: 17, 6, 13, 12, 13, 33, 59, 10, 7, 63 9, 25, 36, 15 Step by step is very much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Which test are you using? t-test?

Comment: I have to use the F-test I believe

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't read the entire question.

Comment: Also I need to find the p-value. I am not sure how to solve this question though.

Comment: @user142696 Do you know how to do it with your calculator or with a chart? Because the equations are kind of difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a calculator, it's really simple. You just plug it in and then go to (this is for TI-83/84) STAT -> TESTS -> 2 Sample F Test and add the two lists (and indicate not equal to). But without the calculator, you will need to find the F-value first. The F-value can be solved by the following equation:

$$F=\frac{\text{variance}_1}{\text{variance}_2}$$

The variance is the standard deviation squared. I think you know how to get the standard deviation or variance by now, but of course doing it by hand is terrible and so I urge you to just plug it into your calculator. When you do, you find that the F-value is:

$$F\approx.2320$$

That is, if you used the popes' data as $\text{variance}_1$ (it won't matter at the end). Cool, now you will need a table for the F-distribution or just use the calculator's `Fcdf(lower,upper,df1,df2)`. The lower bound will be $0$, upper bound will be $F$. Degree of freedom is $n-1$, which for the pope is $23$ and for the other is $13$. From this, you will find that the p-value is $\approx 0.1125\%$. However, remember that it's *two-sided*, and therefore you have to multiply that by $2$ and so the answer is:

$$\therefore p\approx0.2250\%$$